# Border radius only applying to one side of div

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a site for a small business when i ran into a problem, when trying to apply a border radius to a div it only applies it to the left side, i have searched google and stack overflow for a similar answer but haven't found anything.

```css
    body
    {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

    #banner
    {
    background-color: #404040;
    height: 10em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: -0.1em 0.3em;
    }

    #bannerimg
    {
    height: 65%;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    }

    #container
    {
    margin-left: 20em;
    margin-top: -7em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 1em;
    }

    .list
    {
    float: left;
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #067411;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
```

```html
    <header id="banner">
     <div id="container">
      <a class="list">Services</a>
      <a class="list">Remote Support</a>
      <a class="list">Home</a>
      <a class="list">About Us</a>
      <a class="list">Contact Us</a>
     <div>
    </header>
```

If anyone has an answer it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you mean `container`???

Comment: `border-radius` is working but you can't see it because the `background-color` is set on `.list` instead of `#container` https://jsfiddle.net/nrrag4qn/

Answer (score 3):

The background color is overlapping the header div.

```css
    body
    {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

    #banner
    {
    background-color: #404040;
    height: 10em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: -0.1em 0.3em;
    }

    #bannerimg
    {
    height: 65%;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    }

    #container
    {
    margin-left: 20em;
    margin-top: -7em;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 1em;
    }

    .list
    {
    float: left;
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #067411;
    /*background-color: #e0e0e0;*/
    }
```

```html
    <header id="banner">
     <div id="container">
      <a class="list">Services</a>
      <a class="list">Remote Support</a>
      <a class="list">Home</a>
      <a class="list">About Us</a>
      <a class="list">Contact Us</a>
     <div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) styling you can get the result you wish.

```css
body{
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
#banner{
  background-color: #404040;
  height: 7em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: -0.1em 0.3em;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
#bannerimg{
  height: 65%;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#container{
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}
.list{
  padding: 1.1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #067411;
}
```

```html
<header id="banner">
 <div id="container">
  <a class="list">Services</a>
  <a class="list">Remote Support</a>
  <a class="list">Home</a>
  <a class="list">About Us</a>
  <a class="list">Contact Us</a>
 </div>
</header>
```